# Регулярное выражение для получения названий городов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
const arr = [
    "Санкт-Петербург-33",
    "Москва 23",
    "Новомосковск -32",
    "Сыктывкар-4-5"
  ]
 const checkCity = (arr, text) => { return arr.filter(item => item.match("регулярное выражение" === text) }

checkCity(arr, 'Санкт-Петербург'); => Санкт-Петербург
checkCity(arr, 'Москва'); => Москва
checkCity(arr, 'Сыктывкар'); => Сыктывкар
```

На выходе должно быть только название города

Comment: Прям должно? Ну а в чем проблема?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите от кода? Чтобы он вам вернул то, что вы фактически даете ему на вход? Для чего тогда какая-то функция, если на входе вы уже имеете все, что нужно

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе **вы показали**, куда вставлять регулярное выражение, но **если я так сделаю**, то результат будет получен в виде: **boolean**, так как вы используете .filter перед return. Поэтому я предоставил вам **свой пример** решения данной задачи.

```js
const cities = [
  'Санкт-Петербург-33',
  'Москва 23',
  'Новомосковск -32',
  'Сыктывкар-4-5'
];

const checkCity = (cities, text) => {
  return cities.find(city => city.includes(text)).match(text)[0];
};

console.log(checkCity(cities, 'Санкт-Петербург'));
console.log(checkCity(cities, 'Москва'));
console.log(checkCity(cities, 'Сыктывкар'));
```